# tapestry 4 generate valid XHTML

Tags: java, xhtml, tapestry

is it possible to generate valid XHTML in tapestry 4.1.x ?

i specifically need the shell to generate the proper XHTML headers and can work around the actual body content - ie only use specific components that render valid tags/structure.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the @Shell component,

1.change the doctype:

```
doctype="HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'"
```

2.disable dojo script inclusions as the links are not valid XHTML (they include & instead of & in the urls)

```
ajaxDelegate="ognl:null"
```